# ionic cordova barcode scanner - camera not turning on for scan

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

i am using ionic - phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^7.1.2" for barcode scanning, but when i am clicking on scan button - camera looks like below on android emulator.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1xL4.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS5IB.png

here is my code:
scan() {

```
this.options = {
  preferFrontCamera: true,
  showFlipCameraButton: true,
  prompt: "scan the barcode here 111"
}

this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then((barcodeData) => {
  this.data = barcodeData;
  console.log(barcodeData);
}, (err) => {
  this.toast.show(err, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
    toast => {
      console.log(toast);
    }
  );
});
```

}

index.html has the below..
< ion-app style="background: none transparent !important;">

can anyone please help whats wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner.git" source="git" />
```